# Nodejs async-await doubts

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have these 3 functions and I don't understand why c is executed before b completely ends.
I need to use a global variable inside c which is populated by the function d that I call inside b.

```
var globalVariable = {};
async function start() {
    await b();
    await c();
}
    
async function b()
    var targets = {}  //it is a populated array of objects
    Object.keys(targets).forEach(async(key) => {
        await d(key);
        console.log(globalVariable); //it prints the correct value but after the function c is executed
    })
}

async function d(key){
  globalVariable.key = await getValueFromDb();  //returns value 5
}


async function c(){
    await doStuffOnDb();  //not revelant stuff on db
    console.log(globalVariable); //it prints {}
}
```

Comment: `forEach` is never async, even if you supply an `async` callback. It will fire off all of the `d` functions without awaiting them. You need to use a `for x of y` loop instead.

Comment: thank you @lawrence-witt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `forEach` does not wait any of executed handlers.
You either use `Promise.all` or `for of`.

```
await Promise.all(Object.keys(targets).map(key => d(key)))
```

```
for (const key of Object.keys(targets)) {
  await d(key);
  console.log(globalVariable);
}
```